# Объясните плз, как получается квадратная область?

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Вот тут http://jsfiddle.net/8m71qb16/ комрад soledar10 показывает как поместить изображение в квадратную область. 
`div.s{
    max-width: 33%;

}
div.s figure{
    padding-top: 100%;  /* 300px/300px = 1 */
    display: block;
    background: url("https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;

}`
1. Не могу понять, как это работает?
2. Не получается расположить три таких области в ряд (сорри за дубль вопроса)

Comment: Не пойму, что вам нужно? Что-то вроде этого [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2L4e0kf0/)?

Comment: Да, примерно так. Только у меня исходные картинки не будут квадратные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div>   
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.figure{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background: url("https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg")
    no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Квадратная область вырезается за счет cover.
Фидлер: http://jsfiddle.net/8m71qb16/9/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg - оригинальное изображение.

jsfiddle.net/uTHqs/ (cover) - берется область в центре изображения

jsfiddle.net/HZ2FT/ (contain) - изображение вписывается

Comment: В Вашем коде понятно, есть одинаковые высота и ширина, которые и создают  квадратную область. А по моей ссылке есть только ширина. И еще не понятно назначение "padding-top: 100%;  /* 300px/300px = 1 */"

Comment: При указании padding-top в процентах он считается от ширины родительского элемента. У вас ширина 300 пикселей. Высота будет тоже 300 пикселей. В начале специально еще сбрасываются все марджины и паддинги в нули. Это конечно элегантное решение. Но здесь вы все равно хардкодите ширину родителя. Почему явно не задать ширину и высоту?

Comment: Я могу жестко переустанавливаться ширину и высоту через JS (angular). Но сразу в стилях я не могу жестко указать размеры. Разве что ширину 33%. В итоге мне нужно что-то типа [ЭТОГО](http://jsfiddle.net/2L4e0kf0/), но для не квадратных исходных картинок, которые должны отображаться в квадратных областях.